# wordpress Multisite with already used subdomain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have one domain

I need add wordpress multisite

so edit my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
<IFModule mod_url.c>
ServerEncoding UTF-8
ClientEncoding EUC-KR
</IFModule>
```

to
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

```
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IFModule mod_url.c>
ServerEncoding UTF-8
ClientEncoding EUC-KR
</IFModule>
```

after .htaccess changes..

but not working I think that edited .htaccess file is only working on not subdomain sites...

-

I have subdomain site, I want multisite using subfolder type multisite

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WPMU , you must ensure that you have the following code in your wp-config.php

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

this is for the sub directory installation for WPMU

and

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

this is for sub domain installation of WPMU

you can feel the difference here as follows

```
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
```

and

```
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
```

Comment: i already set false to subdomain_install, my question is I already use subdomain site, so I use subdirectory WPMU. 
I want use test.devguru.co.kr/en , actually connection success but test.devguru.co.kr/en/wp-admin not working

Comment: in the multi site setup there you can find a created .htaccees format for your WPMU install, have you tried it?

Comment: yes, not working so i use original (upside .htaccess file)
~/en connection success , but ~/en/wp-admin not working redirection loop

Comment: you must remove this in your .htaccess <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: thanks jothikannan. and I see http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration

Answer (score 0):

finally 
I use this .htaccess option

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

<IfModule mod_url.c>
ServerEncoding UTF-8
ClientEncoding EUC-KR
</IfModule>
```